# How to run script that gets stackoverflow inbox or achievements?

Tags: python, fetch, stackexchange-api

I'm trying to make a script that gets the number of various notifications from websites I use. Unread emails, you number of unread reddit/facebook messages, and I'd also like to get the number of stackoverflow notifications.

Unfortunately googling any python scripts to get information from stack overflow gets me questions *on* stack overflow, not *regarding* stack overflow.

Is it possible to get something along the lines of these two scripts but for stack exchange?

```
import imaplib
import praw

obj = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com","993")
obj.login("","")
obj.select()
obj.search(None,'UnSeen')
unread_gmail = len(obj.search(None, "UnSeen")[1][0].split())

print("Unread emails:", unread_gmail)


r = praw.Reddit(user_agent = "example")
r.login("", "")
i = 0
for message in r.get_unread(): i += 1 
unread_reddit = i

print("Unread reddit:", unread_reddit)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will make a request to the [`/me/notifications/unread`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-unread-notifications) route.

At minimum, this needs to contain an access_token, with a scope containing `read_inbox` and a key. This will return a list of [notifications](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/notification) that have not been read.

To get an access_token, you must [authenticate](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) the user. The key is received after you [register](https://api.stackexchange.com/) your application.

Example:

```
import requests
import json
import pprint

TOKEN = "YOURTOKEN"
KEY = "YOURKEY"
SITE = "stackoverflow"
REQUEST_URL = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me/notifications/unread"

params = {
            "pagesize": 1,
            "filter": 'default',
            "site": SITE,
            "key": KEY,
            "access_token": TOKEN
        }

response = requests.get(REQUEST_URL, params=params)
json_response = response.json()
pprint.pprint(json_response, indent=4)
```

Outputs:

```
{   u'has_more': False,
    u'items': [],
    u'quota_max': 10000,
    u'quota_remaining': 9823}
```

`items` is empty, as I have no notifications at the moment.